# nuxt.js building error when generating static page only?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have developed a nuxt.js application, which works fine when using `nuxt dev` as build method. However, when I try to generate a static page with `nuxt generate`, I get an error:

```
Hash: 206d44a896e029b4cfcd
Version: webpack 3.12.0
Time: 4175ms
             Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
server-bundle.json  343 kB          [emitted]
  nuxt: Call generate:distRemoved hooks (1) +0ms
  nuxt:generate Destination folder cleaned +24s
  nuxt: Call generate:distCopied hooks (1) +87ms
  nuxt:generate Static & build files copied +87ms
  nuxt:render Rendering url /index.vue +0ms
  nuxt:render Rendering url / +74ms
  nuxt: Call generate:page hooks (1) +1s
  nuxt:generate Generate file: \index.html +1s
  nuxt:render Rendering url / +1s
  nuxt: Call generate:done hooks (1) +54ms
  nuxt:generate HTML Files generated in 25.1s +55ms

 Generate errors summary:

 ROUTE  /index.vue

  Error: render function or template not defined in component: anonymous

  - build.js:7396 normalizeRender
    [npm]/[nuxt]/[vue-server-renderer]/build.js:7396:13

  - build.js:7520 renderComponentInner
    [npm]/[nuxt]/[vue-server-renderer]/build.js:7520:3

  - build.js:7491 renderComponent
    [npm]/[nuxt]/[vue-server-renderer]/build.js:7491:5

  - build.js:7407 renderNode
    [npm]/[nuxt]/[vue-server-renderer]/build.js:7407:5

  - build.js:7527 renderComponentInner
    [npm]/[nuxt]/[vue-server-renderer]/build.js:7527:3

  - build.js:7491 renderComponent
    [npm]/[nuxt]/[vue-server-renderer]/build.js:7491:5

  - build.js:7407 renderNode
    [npm]/[nuxt]/[vue-server-renderer]/build.js:7407:5

  - build.js:7527 renderComponentInner
    [npm]/[nuxt]/[vue-server-renderer]/build.js:7527:3

  - build.js:7491 renderComponent
    [npm]/[nuxt]/[vue-server-renderer]/build.js:7491:5

  - build.js:7407 RenderContext.renderNode
    [npm]/[nuxt]/[vue-server-renderer]/build.js:7407:5

  - build.js:2428 RenderContext.next
    [npm]/[nuxt]/[vue-server-renderer]/build.js:2428:14

  - build.js:2441 RenderContext.next
    [npm]/[nuxt]/[vue-server-renderer]/build.js:2441:12

  - build.js:2287 RenderContext.cachedWrite [as write]
    [npm]/[nuxt]/[vue-server-renderer]/build.js:2287:9

  - build.js:2432 RenderContext.next
    [npm]/[nuxt]/[vue-server-renderer]/build.js:2432:16

  - build.js:2287 RenderContext.cachedWrite [as write]
    [npm]/[nuxt]/[vue-server-renderer]/build.js:2287:9

  - build.js:2432 RenderContext.next
    [npm]/[nuxt]/[vue-server-renderer]/build.js:2432:16


  nuxt:generate Generate done +51ms
```

This error is shown as terminal output after calling `nuxt generate`. 'nuxt dev' builds the application without errors and works in the browser as expected.

EDIT: I just noticed: The page *is* actually being built and works as expected in the browser! What is this supposed to mean then?

I have no idea where this error might come from and as the error message is not speaking to me, I also don't know which information I need to attach to this question to make it answerable. Please leave a comment and I will edit it accordingly.

Comment: When this happens? Also actual error will only appear once and then will be this see https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2792

Comment: @Aldarund This happens when calling `nuxt generate` in the terminal. I've added a bit of information to the question to be clearer. Any idea on why a build might fail when generating a static page, although building a ssp-app works fine?

Comment: @Adarund Please see the updates in my question. The app is being built correctly despite of the error. What is that supposed to mean? I've also added more of the terminal output for context.

Comment: hard to tell. looks like something in index.vue. Try to make it empty component and see if it fixes issue. If it fixes - add back your code by pieces until it break